# Why does audio work in Linux but not in Windows?

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-registry, realtek-hd-audio

**Model**: MSI GL63 8SE

**Problem**:

- Headphones audio work in Linux and Windows
- Speakers audio work in Linux only

**Observations**:

1. In Windows, the audio output default seems to be headphones
   connector
2. In Linux, i can switch the audio output manually (it is strange that
   the Linux detect something connected to headphones when there is
   nothing connected). The speakers work although it shows
   "unavailable" (***see [Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p6KZ.jpg)***)
3. In Windows, the audio output should switch automatically when
   connecting the headphones to jack connector or disconnecting. It
   seems that windows detect something connected always (i think my
   jack connector is damage, i am not sure. I had a problem with BIOS
   and someone shared me a BIOS
   https://dr-bios.com/threads/ms-16p7-msi-gl63-8se.53820/)
4. I have installed a lot of driver versions and one time worked! but
   the headphones stopped working (i can't to do to work both. After
   that i installed the drivers again and the headphones worked and
   speakers not) . I installed the drivers from Windows Update. Windows
   Update install "SoftwareComponent", "Semiconductor", etc but it
   seems that not always install the sames (or the same order) (***see
   [Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69DDK.jpg)***)
5. I have hearted that Nahimic could force the headphones output
6. The speakers and headphones share the same device ouput (***see [Photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8e9D.png)- id = 2***)

**What do I want?**

I want the driver and regedit backup (it could be similar model ). I think the regedit save the current audio output so i could do a script for switch between headphones and speakers. Do you have another idea?

**How to make a regedit backup ?**

Windows + R, write "regedit" and find:

***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render***

After that click in export. Make sure the headphones is disconected

**How to make a driver backup ?**

Download "DriverStore Explorer" and export Realtek and Nahimic drivers

https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer/releases/tag/v0.11.92

Comment: You're using an unknown BIOS, so anything can happen. You can find the MSI BIOS for your model [here](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GL63-8SX/support?sub_product=GL63-8SE).

Comment: The original bios give more problems. With original bios get aleatory freeze. The bios used share the same motherboard